# I am not able to use the below code to login to a website using Internet Explorer. It says runtime error 424 - Object required

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The line where I'm getting the error is :
oBrowser.Document.getElementById("LOGUSER").Value = "yyyyyyyy"

Below is the full code:

```
Sub website()
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim sURL As String
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

    sURL = "https://xyxyxyxyxyyyx"
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium

    oBrowser.Silent = True
    oBrowser.navigate sURL

    Do Until oBrowser.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
    oBrowser.Visible = True



    oBrowser.Document.getElementById("LOGUSER").Value = "yyyyyyyyy"
        oBrowser.Document.getElementById("LOGPASS").Value = "sgsgrger"

    oBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login").Click

    Do Until Not oBrowser.Busy And oBrowser.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Fix code indentation (use `{}` button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that HTML element with an ID **LOGUSER** is available in your web page.

If your code is not able to find that element than it will generate this error.

Try to check that spelling is correct and it was written exactly as in your web page.

I try to test your code and I try to modify it little bit and looks like it is working fine on my side.

```
Sub website()

On Error GoTo 0

Dim sURL As String
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

sURL = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\75.html"

Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


oBrowser.navigate sURL

Do Until oBrowser.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
oBrowser.Visible = True


oBrowser.Document.getElementById("LOGUSER").Value = "abcd"
oBrowser.Document.getElementById("LOGPASS").Value = "xyz"

oBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login").Click


End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

You can try to check on your side and let us know if issue persist, We will try to provide further suggestions.